# Import a Photoshop Shape (Button) without the Background from Photoshop android

Tags: android, button, layout, background-image, photoshop

I have no idea how to import my Photoshop shape that I made for my buttons, into android, without it bringing along the background. Even if i set the Background in photoshop to Transparent and save it as a PNG, the background still takes up space when I use it in android as an android:background for my Button. Please Help!

Also, a quick side note: If i make the buttons the appropriate px size that is equivalent to the right mdpi, hdpi, and xdpi, will it still be an issue if it doesn't look proportional in the GraphicalLayout of Eclipse? Like will it adjust itself on the screen?

Answer (score 1):

Ok ok ok!

What you need to do, is to create a CUSTOM BUTTON instead of actually just using a background.

First, you need 3 png's:

1) When the button is idle.
2) When the button is pressed.
3) When the button is highlighted.

The Highlighted and idle could use the same image if you dont need such effect.

Create a resource in your drawable carpet. I usually start with MDPI then move on to the bigger screensizes, but this will give you the main idea.

The resource would be your entire button. It goes like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed"
      android:state_pressed="true" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/button_focused"
      android:state_focused="true" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/button_idle" />
</selector>
```

Let's name it "custom_button.xml"

The Selector is THE BUTTON.
You will need to add the 3 resources explained above "button_pressed" is what the button should look when pressed. And so on... the names are self explanatory.

Now in your layout page you could use 2 ways to create your button.

1) If the button is an ImageButton:

```
<ImageButton
    android:src="@drawable/custom_button"
    android:background="@null"
    ...
```

You have to eliminate the background in this case.

2) If the button is a Normal button with text:

```
<ImageButton
    android:background="@drawable/custom_button"
    ...
```

In this case you can add padding to make it contain text.

And yes, you would have to work with photoshop for the actual size of the button. The button can strech or crop when it grows but the results would be not as good and clean as if you nail the right size from photoshop.

Comment: So when I import my button from photoshop thats measured in px (lets say 140x60 for mdpi) i would put that in the mdpi folder and then create the appropriate sizes based on the ratios for hdpi, xdpi, and so on and then save them as drawables in their folders. 

After all that has been done, would I make separate resources (like the one you described above with pressed, highlighted and all...which is awesome!) for each dpi measurement? so One for mdpi which points to the drawables that have beed scaled for mdpi, then another for hdpi which has been scaled appropriately for hdpi and so on?

Comment: You should add only 1 button resource. And add each size of the images WITH THE SAME NAME. WHen the device tries to load the resource, Android will ask first for the optimal size. if not found will move to the next most optimal and so on.